# How to retrieve the final shipping amount of table rate in code?

Tags: shipping, shipping-methods, table-rates

I want to show to the customer the final tax rate amount that he will pay based on my tablerates.csv which contains my rules. Is there any function which i can call to obtain this value before final step? Maybe a controller or model.